# Create new class subclassing an existing class with same name

Tags: python

I'm in the middle of optimizing an existing codebase, where I've to heavily use the old classes and methods, and create fresh module in place.

Existing structure is like following (there are many more classes like `FooBar`, and also a few more submodules and `file.py`s)

`existing/file.py`

```
import foo
from bar import baz

Variables declaration
Some format declaration
logger declaration

Class FooBar(object):
    def some_method(self):
        pass
```

I'm currently thinking of doing it in the following which doesn't look like the right way to do it, though it works.

`new/file.py`

```
from exisiting.file import *

Class FooBar(FooBar):
    def some_method2(self):
        pass
```

What would be the pythonic way of doing this?

The other option I was thinking of was to maybe import each of the classes separately with some other name, but the way I see it, the `import *` already covers that.

PS: Here is a demo of how this works

```
class Foo():
    def bar(self):
        print "class Foo(), method bar()"

class Foo(Foo):
    def barbar(self):
        print "class Foo(Foo), method barbar()"

variable = Foo()

variable.bar()
"class Foo(), method bar()"

variable.barbar()
"class Foo(Foo), method barbar()"
```

Comment: Are you hoping to overwrite all references to the existing class with your own subclass?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I'm trying to create new subclasses for each of the original classes (around 25 in total), so that I can access the parent class's method, while also defining new methods for the child class. The other requirement is to retain the existing class nomenclature.

Comment: @DanielRoseman To further explain, the current approach I've works but it looks really hackish and am not sure if that is the pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Honestly? Start fresh. Copy `existing/file.py` to `new/file.py` and just edit it to match the new code. Building on top of the old code like this is fragile.

Comment: @chepner I tried that initially, but the existing code is around 5k+ lines and is really messed up. I am hoping to change it incrementally now, method by method, class by class, introducing fresh methods when needed and overriding existing methods one by one. For things to work continuously, I would need all remaining unchanged methods to behave normally, so subclassing all the original classes seemed like a very good idea. Only problem is, I am not sure if subclassing a parent class with same name is pythonic at all, and if there are any unintended side effects I've missed.

Comment: I don't think there are any downsides other than making the code harder to understand, especially with an `import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you're looking for here, but you could import every class in the following way:

```
from existing.file import Foo as oldFoo
```

You could then create a new class named Foo which extends oldFoo